# Adding * to command line arguments adds additional arguments

Tags: go, build, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a simple command line calculator which takes in 3 arguments operator int1 int2 where operator is can be either +,-,*,/ whenever I add * to the arguments it adds additional arguments. How would I go about reading * from arguments.

OS: `Ubuntu x64`
Build Command: `go build main.go`

Executed with + as a command line argument
Run Command: `./main + 2 2`
Output: `[./main + 2 2]`

Executed with * as a command line argument
Run Command: `./main * 2 2`
Output: `[./main build main main.go main.go.bak 2 2]`

#### Example Code

```golang
package main

import (
  "os"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  args := os.Args
  fmt.Println(args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the command line, `*` is replaced with all files and directories in the current directory before the command is actually ran. In order to avoid this, instead do `.\main "*" 2 2`